# mouseenter using live or delegate?

Tags: delegates, live, jquery, mouseenter

I want to re-open a question someone else asked. What's the best way to emulate mouseenter with live or delegate? The original question was here:

[How should I emulate a mouseenter event using jquery's live functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891584/how-should-i-emulate-a-mouseenter-event-using-jquerys-live-functionality)

And the OP's proposal was:

```
// mouseenter emulation
jQuery('.selector').live('mouseover',function (e) {
    // live sees all mouseover events within the selector
    // only concerned about events where the selector is the target
    if (this != e.target) return; 
    // examine relatedTarget's parents to see if target is a parent. 
    // if target is a parent, we're "leaving" not entering
    var entering = true;
    jQuery(e.relatedTarget).parents().each(function () {
            if (this == e.target) {
                entering = false;
                return false; // found; stop searching
            }
    });
    if (!entering) return;
    /*
     the rest of my code 
     */
});
```

Comment: I don't understand the "question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
$("#id").delegate(".selector", "mouseover", function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("bound")){                                                                                                          
        $(this).hover(function(){
            alert('entering');
        },
        function(){
            alert('leaving');
        }).mouseover().addClass("bound");
    }
});
```

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.cms_tabs_edit').delegate('li', 'mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});

$('ul.cms_tabs_edit').delegate('li', 'mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```